# How to verify a method gets called with an object whose some fields may be anyObject() while others have a specific value?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest, hamcrest

I'm using Mockito with ScalaTest. Consider this simplified example.

Model case class:

```
case class Batch(batchId: Long, 
                 timestamp: Option[LocalDateTime] = Some(LocalDateTime.now),
                 invoicesReceived: Option[Int])
```

In my test I'm mocking a class called BatchRepository which has a method with this signature:

```
def create(conn: Connection, batch: Batch): Long
```

Relevant bit of test code:

```
verify(batchRepository, times(1)).create(anyObject(),
  Batch(anyLong(), anyObject(), Matchers.eq(Some(1))))
)
```

**The beef is**: I'd like to verify that the code under test calls the mocked repository method with whatever Connection and a Batch instance with whatever id and timestamp, but `invoicesReceived` being exactly `Some(1)`.

Using Mockito, is this possible at all, and if so, how?

The production code creates a new Batch which sets the timestamp to current moment, so I think it's pretty much impossible to create a real Batch object in the test for the `verify()` call with the exact same timestamp. So at least for the timestamp I'd need `anyObject()`.

I tried many variations, like wrapping the whole Batch in `Matchers.eq()`, but I haven't found anything that works:

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 2 matchers expected, 4 recorded [...]

I'd be happy to hear I'm using matchers all wrong if there turns out to be some alternative way to use Mockito to test what I want.

(I was having hard time writing a good name for this question; please edit or leave a comment if you understand what I'm asking and can express it more succinctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to `verify` two calls at once - `create` and `Batch.apply`. Can't do that.

One way to do what you want is `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[Batch])
verify(batchRepository).create(any(), captor.capture)
captor.getValue should matchPattern {
  case Batch(_, _, Some(1)) => 
}
// or just `captor.getValue.infoReceived shouldBe Some(1)`
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was using `FunSuite` so `should matchPattern` doesn't seem to be available but `captor.getValue match` and then `case _ => fail` seems clean enough.

Comment: Why do you keep reverting the answer to `any` which does not compile in my case? Wouldn't it be more useful to have a version that will actually *work* as-is for me and future readers? (`any` produces "polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type"; `any()` works.)

Comment: Just mix in `Matchers` to get the `matchPattern` to work. 
As for `any` without parens, I guess, you are right ... Turns out I just have a  workaround in my codebase: `def any[T] = Matchers.any()` for so long, that I forgot about it :) I was reverting it because I don't appreciate people editing my stuff without asking first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)? it supports partial functions as matchers so you could just write

```
verify(batchRepository, times(1)).create(any, argMatching({case Batch(_, _, Some(1)) => }))
```

Or even better if you use the idiomatic syntax

```
batchRepository.create(*, argMatching({case Batch(_, _, Some(1)) => })) was called
```